# Text displayed in debug window instead of popup window of Kivy App

Tags: python, debugging, popup, kivy

I encountered some weird behavior of Kivy when trying to place the results of some analysis in a popup window of my App. By the button activation I can get a popup window (that should display the results of the analysis but is empty) and then my results are displayed in a debug window. But I'd like to see them in a popup. No error, no traceback, just weirdness.

This is how it looks like:

[image]

This is the line that runs a popup:

```
show_syllsoutput_popup()
```

This is the line that should populate it but populates debug window instead:

```
try: SyllOutputPopup.screen_output_label.text = cfd_syll.tabulate()
```

So, the question is how to put `cfd_syll.tabulate()` into this popup (.kv):

```
<SyllOutputPopup>:

    FloatLayout:

        Label:

            id: screen_output_label
            font_size: 12
            pos: 100, 120
```

=============================================================

Alternative test: if I try to populate output popup by this:

```
SyllOutputPopup.screen_output_label.text = cfd_syll.tabulate()
```

(without `try:`), I get `AttributeError: type object 'SyllOutputPopup' has no attribute 'screen_output_label'`

Here is the full traceback, in case it'd be helpful:

```
File "C:\Users\gavrk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
  "__main__", mod_spec)
File "C:\Users\gavrk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
  exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\GUI Projects\gercort\main.py", line 190, in <module>
  Gercort().run()
File "C:\Users\gavrk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 855, in run
  runTouchApp()
File "C:\Users\gavrk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 504, in runTouchApp
  EventLoop.window.mainloop()
File "C:\Users\gavrk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 747, in mainloop
  self._mainloop()
File "C:\Users\gavrk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 479, in _mainloop
  EventLoop.idle()
File "C:\Users\gavrk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 342, in idle
  self.dispatch_input()
File "C:\Users\gavrk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 327, in dispatch_input
  post_dispatch_input(*pop(0))
File "C:\Users\gavrk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 293, in post_dispatch_input
  wid.dispatch('on_touch_up', me)
File "C:\Users\gavrk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\kivy\_event.cp37-win32.pyd", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
File "C:\Users\gavrk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\behaviors\button.py", line 179, in on_touch_up
  self.dispatch('on_release')
File "C:\Users\gavrk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\kivy\_event.cp37-win32.pyd", line 703, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
File "C:\Users\gavrk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\kivy\_event.cp37-win32.pyd", line 1214, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch
File "C:\Users\gavrk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\kivy\_event.cp37-win32.pyd", line 1098, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch
File "C:\Users\gavrk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 64, in custom_callback
  exec(__kvlang__.co_value, idmap)
File "C:\GUI Projects\gercort\gercort.kv", line 484, in <module>
  on_release: root.output_toscreen(root.filepath)
File "C:\GUI Projects\gercort\main.py", line 135, in output_toscreen
  SyllOutputPopup.screen_output_label.text = cfd_syll.tabulate() # populate the popup

builtins.AttributeError: type object 'SyllOutputPopup' has no attribute 'screen_output_label'
```

Would be grateful for any help! I don't know what parts of code would be helpful, so I apologize in advance, any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

==================================================================

Additional info:

`cfd_syll` is defined in the fourth line of:

```
    def output_toscreen(сorpus_root, *args):

        corpus = PlaintextCorpusReader(args[0], '.*')
        cfd_syll = nltk.ConditionalFreqDist(
            (textname, num_syll)
            for textname in corpus.fileids()
            for num_syll in [len(w) for w in ''.join(char for char in reduce_dip(corpus.raw(fileids=textname)) if char in vowels).split()])

        show_syllsoutput_popup() # run the popup

        try: SyllOutputPopup.screen_output_label.text = cfd_syll.tabulate() # populate the popup

        except: pass
```

Here is the Popup class:

```
class SyllOutputPopup(FloatLayout):
    pass
```

Here is definition of `show_syllsoutput_popup`:

```
def show_syllsoutput_popup():
    show = SyllOutputPopup() # Create a new instance of the LicensePopup class 

    SyllOutputPopupWindow = Popup(title="Output", content=show, size_hint=(None,None),size=(600,400)) 
    # Create the popup window

    SyllOutputPopupWindow.open() # show the popup
```

In the .kv Popup is defined as:

```
<SyllOutputPopup>:

    FloatLayout:

        Label:

            id: screen_output_label
            font_size: 12
            pos: 100, 120
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

screen_output_label is not the parameter of your class, it's widget's id, so that line

```
SyllOutputPopup.screen_output_label.text = cfd_syll.tabulate()
```

is wrong, you should use:

```
SyllOutputPopup.ids.screen_output_label.text = cfd_syll.tabulate()
```

==========

Also you are creating several objects of SyllOutputPopup class. You put the text in one object:

```
try: SyllOutputPopup.ids.screen_output_label.text = cfd_syll.tabulate()
```

And then you create new object, which is blank and has empty Label, and you show it:

```
show = SyllOutputPopup() # Create a new instance
    SyllOutputPopupWindow = Popup(title="Output", content=show, size_hint=(None,None),size=(600,400)) 
    SyllOutputPopupWindow.open()
```

You should use one object - set the text there and then show exactly that object, something like:

```
    def output_toscreen(сorpus_root, *args):

        corpus = PlaintextCorpusReader(args[0], '.*')
        cfd_syll = nltk.ConditionalFreqDist(
            (textname, num_syll)
            for textname in corpus.fileids()
            for num_syll in [len(w) for w in ''.join(char for char in reduce_dip(corpus.raw(fileids=textname)) if char in vowels).split()])
        # that will be your object
        self.sylloutputpopup = SyllOutputPopup()
        self.sylloutputpopup.ids.screen_output_label.text = cfd_syll.tabulate()
        show_syllsoutput_popup() # run the popup

def show_syllsoutput_popup():
    show = self.sylloutputpopup
    SyllOutputPopupWindow = Popup(title="Output", content=show, size_hint=(None,None),size=(600,400)) 
    SyllOutputPopupWindow.open()
```

But that will work only if both of functions above are in the same class.

Comment: Didn't work out, regrettably (as well as adding `id` instead of `ids`). Please see "Additional info".

Comment: @Gavrk I've added something to my answer, check it.

Comment: Yep, it requires `self` to be an argument of `output_toscreen`. If I add `self` to arguments I get `ValueError: None is not allowed for Label.text` and `cfd_syll.tabulate()` is still printed in the debug window

Comment: @Gavrk well, you should make cfd_syll.tabulate() be string, because Label.text accepts strings. Check the type of it like you did yesterday.

Comment: It's <class 'NoneType'> =(

Comment: @Gavrk yeah, error message told so. Try to do print(cfd_syll.tabulate()) and tell me how's it look like.

Comment: Like a table. It's on the screenshot at the beginning of the issue description. But it's still in the shell. I actually managed to put a table on the popup by `str(DataFrame(cfd_syll))` but Dataframe's tables look ripped and ugly.

Comment: @Gavrk and what type is cfd_syll? Is it a dict? Maybe you need to do tabulation by yourself with loops and lots of labels in Grid Layout. I'll try to think about more simple solution.

Comment: It's <class 'nltk.probability.ConditionalFreqDist'>. Grid Layout is not very good for this purpose, I assume, because of different number of rows and columns each time them analysis is performed. I'll play with Dataframe first.